# pysvn on a webserver

Tags: python, svn, web-hosting, pysvn

Are there any web hosting providers who have pysvn (http://pysvn.tigris.org/) included in their python modules, or who allow you to add additional modules such that I can install it myself? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shell access you can install pretty much anything to your home directory.  Just make sure the path you install the module to is added to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

say `/home/harry` is your home directory, you install pysvn to `/home/harry/lib` in your .bash_profile add:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/harry/lib:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

login and log out again.  This will put it into the environment and python will find the modules in `/home/harry/lib`  see the python docs on [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more info on how python searches for modules.

The only real caveat is, if your host doesn't have all the files needed to build pysvn (such as svn header files), you'll have to install them also.

with that said I like webfaction (which is nice towards these things and python development) and this question might be better in webmasters.stackexchange.com